# A basic sequence convergence question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the following iterative algorithm

$$x_{n+1} = x_n + a(n)h(x_n)$$

where $x_n$'s are bounded and $h$ is lipschitz( and hence also bounded) and $a_n \rightarrow 0$. Is $x_n$ converges ? Assume some initial condition.

Now consider the function $X^0[0,\infty)$ defined by $X^0(t) = x_n + h(x_n)(t-t_n)$ when $t \in [t_n, t_{n+1}]$, so it is just the interpolated process of the algorithm at the time instants $t_n$ where $t_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a(i)$. then define $X^n(t) = X^0(t+t_n)$. Then a book claims that $X^n(.)$ is equicontinuous. For that I need $X^0(.)$ to be uniformly continuous. For that I need $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} X^0(t)$ to exist. For that I need $x_n$ to converge. But $x_n$ does not converge. Then how to prove the equicontinuity

Comment: @derpy: Sorry I forgot to say the main condition $a_n -> 0$. You can even assume that $a_n \downarrow 0$. Then also I don't think $x_n$ converges unless we have $\sum_n a_n < \infty$.

Comment: @derpy The OP said that the $x_n$ are bounded, so you can't use your example. The question is: does it converge?

Comment: @user148951 My bad, missed the condition of boundedness on the $ x_n $. Give me a minute to think about it.

Comment: @user148951 Forget about my previous answer, it was wrong. I can't come up with a counterexample right now, but I'm pretty sure your conditions aren't enough to say that $ x_n $ will converge.

Comment: @derpy: Have you seen my changes also ?

Comment: @user148951 I did. The Lipschitz condition on $ h $ may just be the saving grace, since I think I could find a counterexample if $ h $ were not required to be continuous. As is, I'm not sure what can be said.

Comment: It looks like the answer to your [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019832/analysis-question-on-whether-a-bounded-sequence-satifying-x-n-x-n-1-rightar) also answers this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna make some assumptions, suggested in the comments:

i): $a_n \downarrow 0$ => $a_n$ positive,  amongst other things.

I'll prove something first: if  $\sum a_n $ diverges to $+\infty$, then $(x_n)$ doesn't converge.

Indeed, if $(x_n) \rightarrow x $ ; $(h(x_n)) \rightarrow h(x)  $ (since h is continuous).

We get : $ x_{n+1} -x_n $ ~ $a_n*h(x) $

You can sum partial sums of positive terms  and you get :

$ x_n -x_1 $ ~ $h(x)*A_n$ ; where $A_n$ is the partial sum of the $a_k$. So $(x_n)$ diverges, and we get an absurdity. We can now assume that $\sum a_n $ converges (positive terms, either diverges to $+\infty$
 or converges).

$|x_{n+1}-x_n| = a_n*|h(x_n)|$ . $(x_n)$ bounded $\implies$  $(h(x_n))$ bounded

=> $|x_{n+1}-x_n| \leq a_n*H$

But $\sum a_n$ converges, then so does $\sum |x_{n+1}-x_n|$. Let $v_n = x_{n+1}-x_n$. here we have proved that $\sum v_n$ converges absolutely, so $\sum v_n$ converges ie :

$ V_n = \sum_{k=1}^n (x_{k+1}-x_k) = x_{n+1} - x_1 $ converges. Hence $(x_n)$ converges.

Comment: Are you saying the for $x_n$ to converges the necessary condition is $\sum a(n)$ converges. this does not seem to be true. I don't understand the lines where you replace $h(x_n)$ by $h(x)$.

Comment: @user148951 I know why: if h(x)=0... I wrote this too quickly. At least we know that if $\sum a_n$ converges, then so does $x_n$ but you may have already foun it :), sorry. I'll try to refine the proof..