# Analysis question on whether a bounded sequence satifying $x_n - x_{n-1}\rightarrow 0$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have a bounded sequence $x_n$ such that $x_{n+1} - x_n \to 0$. Is it true that the sequence converges ? If not (which is most likely), what is the minimum condition I have to add ?

Comment: There are so many people asking this recently... Sadly I cannot find those questions. The answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}, x_n=\sin(a_n)$ Clearly $x_n$ is not convergent (it goes up and down along the sine curve with smaller and smaller steps), $x_n$ is bounded, but by Mean value theorem, $$|x_n-x_{n-1}|=|\sin(a_n)-\sin(a_{n-1})|= |\cos(z)||a_n-a_{n-1}|\leq |a_n-a_{n-1}|\to 0$$

And if you write $x_n=\sum (x_n-x_{n-1})$, one sufficient condition for the series converges (so is $x_n$) is $|x_n-x_{n-1}|\leq b_n, \forall n$ where $\sum b_n<\infty$, then you can use M-Test.

The "minimum condition" in your question is not well-defined.

Comment: The counterexample is valid, but it isn't clear that your proof that $|x_n-x_{n-1}|=|sin(a_n)-sin(a_{n-1})| \to 0 $ is correct. Use the trig identity sin(α) – sin(β) = 2cos[1/2(α + β)] sin[1/2(α-β)] to establish this.

Comment: @TomCollinge I am using Mean value theorem.

Comment: It's clearer after your edit.

Answer (score 0):

No. Counterexample:
$$
1,\frac12,1,\frac23,\frac13,\frac23,1,\frac34,\frac24,\frac14,\frac24,\frac34,1,\frac45,\frac35,\frac25,\frac15,\frac25,\frac35,\frac45,1,\dots
$$
It is difficult to give a minimum condition. One would be $\sum(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ converges, but this is equivalent to the convergence of $x_n$. Based on this, a *sufficient* condiution would be $n^a|x_{n+1}-x_n|$ bounded for some $a>1$.

Comment: How does that sequence satisfy OP's condition? It seems to me that $ x_{n+1} - x_n $ admits 1 as a limit point. It should be $ 1,\frac 1 2,1,\frac 2 3,\frac 1 3,\frac 2 3,1,... $.

Comment: $1$ is a limit point, but the sequence does not converge.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre My point is that the partial differences are not convergent, which contradicts OP's hypothesis.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I nave edited the answer.