# Does $b_n = a_{n+1} - a_n $ is a zero sequence implies $a_n$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $b_n = a_{n+1} - a_n $ be a zero sequence. According to my intuition, I would say that $a_n$ converges. But my solution says otherwise. How could that be? I just can't find a counterexample.

Comment: A zero sequence? Is that one that converges to zero? Like say $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n$?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1019832/42969.

Comment: You have that a sequence converges if it's cauchy, since this one is a special case of cauchy $m=n+1$, one would expect that there exists such sequence so that there exists a $m$ such that $a_n-a_m$ doesn't go to $0$. Intuitively, a sequence which diverges slowly will satisfy $a_{n+1}-a_n\to 0$.

Comment: Counterexample $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 3):

$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k$$

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $a_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Why the downvote ???????????????

Answer (score -1):

Another nice example.  $a_n = \sqrt{n}$.  Show that
$$
\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} \to 0\qquad\text{but}\qquad
\sqrt{n} \to +\infty
$$